# Scraping .txt files for many files that are formatted similarly

Tags: r

I converted some .pdf's into .txt files using R and am having trouble finding a way to scrape them to ultimately construct a data frame. I am new to text scraping, so please have mercy on my ignorance.

This is the format of the .txt file and I am mainly interested in the numbers and headers. Any recommendations are much appreciated.

```
   Township of Buena Vista
                                                                             General Election Results - November 2, 2010
                                                                 Prepared by the Office of Edward P. McGettigan, Atlantic County Clerk




                           Township Committee                                                Public Count

                                       Mary Ann
            Peter C.      Richard                    Henry L.      Total         Total          Total          Total           Total
                                      Micheletti-
           Bylone, Sr.     Harlan                    Coia, Jr.    Machine       Vote By      Provisional     Emergency         Public
                                        Levari
Ward       Democratic    Democratic                 Republican     Count         Mail          Count           Count           Count
                                      Republican
District
 D-1          205           195          230           223          436           113            16                            565
 D-2          202           160          275           261          459                                                        459
 D-3          331           346          99            87           457                                                        457
 D-4          215           205          164           152          377                                                        377
 D-5          104           95           169           166          271                                                        271
 D-6          77            70           109           108          188                                                        188
```

I would like the output to be something in tabular form like

```
                               Mary Ann
            Peter C.      Richard                    Henry L.      Total         Total          Total          Total           Total
                                      Micheletti-
           Bylone, Sr.     Harlan                    Coia, Jr.    Machine       Vote By      Provisional     Emergency         Public
                                        Levari
           Democratic    Democratic                 Republican     Count         Mail          Count           Count           Count
                                      Republican
District
 D-1          205           195          230           223          436           113            16                            565
 D-2          202           160          275           261          459                                                        459
 D-3          331           346          99            87           457                                                        457
 D-4          215           205          164           152          377                                                        377
 D-5          104           95           169           166          271                                                        271
 D-6          77            70           109           108          188                                                        188
```

except with the names and party affiliation as one character string. The goal is to merge this with other files like it to create a dataset.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I edited to reflect your question.

Comment: The biggest problem I'm seeing here is that you have no separators between text, and you can't even be guaranteed that related data will be on the same lines. If you can be guaranteed the 'columns' are always the same widths you could use `?read.fwf` to specify the widths of each column of data. That would be a starting point at least.

Comment: Does the line containing "District" seperate the "data" from the column names?

Comment: Yes, "District" is on it's own line

Comment: @thelatemail I had tried that earlier, but since the character widths aren't fixed, I might as well just transcribe the documents myself. Good idea though!

Comment: @MartinGal That's a really good idea. I could use something like `"District %in% Page[i]` in a for loop and then subset the list based on what the loop returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always going to be ugly, but this should be somewhat automated:

```
# read it in as individual lines
rl <- readLines(textConnection(txt))
# drop all the extra info at top
rl <- rl[-(1:9)]

# just keep header
dist <- which(rl == "District")
hd <- head(rl, dist - 1)

# make everything same length and split characters
hd <- lapply(strsplit(hd, ""), `length<-`, max(nchar(hd)))
hd <- lapply(hd, function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), " "))

# find where spaces are in common in all rows
wdths <- rle(Reduce(`&`, lapply(hd, `==`, " ")))$lengths

# read it all in, ignoring district row
out <- read.fwf(textConnection(rl[-dist]), widths=wdths )
# keep those columns that aren't all NA 
out <- out[!sapply(out, function(x) all(is.na(x)) )]

# collapse the header
hdr <- sapply(head(out, dist - 1), 
       function(x) trimws(gsub("\\s+", " ", paste(na.omit(x), collapse=" "))))

# finalise by joining
setNames(
  data.frame(lapply(tail(out, -(dist-1)), type.convert, as.is=TRUE)),
  hdr
)
```

Result:

```
#  Ward Peter C. Bylone, Sr. Democratic Richard Harlan Democratic
#1  D-1                             205                       195
#2  D-2                             202                       160
#3  D-3                             331                       346
#4  D-4                             215                       205
#5  D-5                             104                        95
#6  D-6                              77                        70
#  Mary Ann Micheletti- Levari Republican Henry L. Coia, Jr. Republican
#1                                    230                           223
#2                                    275                           261
#3                                     99                            87
#4                                    164                           152
#5                                    169                           166
#6                                    109                           108
#  Total Machine Count Total Vote By Mail Total Provisional Count
#1                 436                113                      16
#2                 459                 NA                      NA
#3                 457                 NA                      NA
#4                 377                 NA                      NA
#5                 271                 NA                      NA
#6                 188                 NA                      NA
#  Total Emergency Count Total Public Count
#1                    NA                565
#2                    NA                459
#3                    NA                457
#4                    NA                377
#5                    NA                271
#6                    NA                188
```

The example `txt` used was:

```
"   Township of Buena Vista\n                                                                             General Election Results - November 2, 2010\n                                                                 Prepared by the Office of Edward P. McGettigan, Atlantic County Clerk\n\n\n\n\n                           Township Committee                                                Public Count\n\n                                       Mary Ann\n            Peter C.      Richard                    Henry L.      Total         Total          Total          Total           Total\n                                      Micheletti-\n           Bylone, Sr.     Harlan                    Coia, Jr.    Machine       Vote By      Provisional     Emergency         Public\n                                        Levari\nWard       Democratic    Democratic                 Republican     Count         Mail          Count           Count           Count\n                                      Republican\nDistrict\n D-1          205           195          230           223          436           113            16                            565\n D-2          202           160          275           261          459                                                        459\n D-3          331           346          99            87           457                                                        457\n D-4          215           205          164           152          377                                                        377\n D-5          104           95           169           166          271                                                        271\n D-6          77            70           109           108          188                                                        188"
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can generalize this approach, but I don't think, it is very stable when used with other data than the example data.

I put your example into a file named `example.txt`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

input <- read_lines("example.txt")

input[as.logical(cumsum(input == "District"))] %>% 
  tibble() %>% 
  slice(-1) %>% 
  mutate(count = str_replace_all(string = ., "\\s{9,12}", ";")) %>%
  select(-.) %>% 
  separate(col = count, into = c("District", as.character(1:9)), sep = ";") %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), str_trim),
         across(as.character(1:9), as.integer))
```

returns

```r
# A tibble: 6 x 10
  District   `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`   `6`   `7`   `8`   `9`
  <chr>    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 D-1        205   195   230   223   436   113    16    NA   565
2 D-2        202   160   275   261   459    NA    NA    NA   459
3 D-3        331   346    99    87   457    NA    NA    NA   457
4 D-4        215   205   164   152   377    NA    NA    NA   377
5 D-5        104    95   169   166   271    NA    NA    NA   271
6 D-6         77    70   109   108   188    NA    NA    NA   188
```

Creating the column names (the candidate names) is a tricky task. Depending on the counts, perhaps it is necessary to adjust the spaces replaced with ";": `\\s{9,12}` means replace at least 9 up to 12 space characters.

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you so much! Can you please explain the line `str_replace_all(string = ., "\\s{9,12}", ";"))` seems like a regex thing to me.

Comment: See the short explanation. But, as I stated, I'm in doubt that you can apply this solution on other datasets. And for the creating of the column names I'm lacking an approach.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I will try to generalize this, but even if I can't, it will probably be quicker than transcribing them all by hand. 30 documents for 23 counties about 300-400 pages each.